# Why am I shown on the "top users" tag page list when I have such little score in the tag?

Tags: support, tag-score, top-users

I wonder what the logic is behind the "top users" tab page.

For example, the [C++ tag top user tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers) shows me at the bottom of the top askers and top answerers. Obviously I don't belong to those lists (yet).

I wonder if the page displays me always at the bottom. If yes, what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't fit in that top list, but you have some kind of score in that list, it adds you at the bottom so you can see where you stand...